# Restrict item in PyQt4‏ using itemChange()

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt

I tried using the Qt documentation [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) to restrict the [rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyxXT.jpg) to the area of the scene but it still fails, someone has an alternative to do this?

My code, the QGraphicsView instance was created in Qt Desginer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
from screen import *

class MovableItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, rectang, *args, **kwargs):
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, rectang, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable |
                  QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)

        self.pen = QPen(Qt.darkMagenta)
        self.pen.setWidth(4)

        self.setPen(self.pen)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange and self.scene():
            # value is the new position.
            self.newPos = value.toPointF()
            self.rect = self.scene().sceneRect()

            if not(self.rect.contains(self.newPos)):
            # Keep the item inside the scene rect.
                self.newPos.setX(min(self.rect.right(), max(self.newPos.x(), self.rect.left())))
                self.newPos.setY(min(self.rect.bottom(), max(self.newPos.y(), self.rect.top())))

                return self.newPos

        return QGraphicsRectItem.itemChange(self, change, value)


class Main(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.cena.setScene(self.scene)
        self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("01.png"))

        self. graph = MovableItem(2, 2, 300, 150)

        self.scene.addItem(self.graph)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.cena.fitInView(self.scene.sceneRect(), Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main()
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

Use [`setSceneRect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#sceneRect-prop) in your main `Main()`, to set the size of the scene.

Second:

Actually the example of the documentation is wrong, therefore, to adjust the rectangle to the scene, delete this `if` and subtract, in `min`, the parameters `right` and `bottom` by the rectangle dimensions `right` and `bottom` in `setX` and `setY`. Replace this part of your code:

```
if not(self.rect.contains(self.newPos)):
# Keep the item inside the scene rect.
    self.newPos.setX(min(self.rect.right(), max(self.newPos.x(), self.rect.left())))
    self.newPos.setY(min(self.rect.bottom(), max(self.newPos.y(), self.rect.top())))

    return self.newPos
```

For:

```
self.newPos.setX(min(self.rect.right()-self.boundingRect().right(), max(self.newPos.x(), self.rect.left())))
self.newPos.setY(min(self.rect.bottom()-self.boundingRect().bottom(), max(self.newPos.y(), self.rect.top())))

return self.newPos
```